# Bare Sql Server - Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server

This is very similar to [Introducing Foreign key Constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796434/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-on-table-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade), except that the answer to that question does not explain the rationale behind the error.

I have the following simple schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DbInfo](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [DbInfo1Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DbInfo2Id] [int] NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_DbInfo_DbInfo1Id] FOREIGN KEY([DbInfo1Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DbInfo] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Now I would like to add the same constraint to the column `MyTable.DbInfo2Id`:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_DbInfo_DbInfo2Id] FOREIGN KEY ([DbInfo2Id])
REFERENCES [DbInfo] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But I get the following error:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_MyTable_DbInfo_DbInfo2Id' on table 'MyTable' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

You can reproduce it in the [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4a276/1)

Why what I am doing here is problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Because the CASCDE mode will drop ID that can possibly be use by the other constraints that will cause cascade too that will drop ID that can possibly be use by the primer constraints that will cause cascade too... an so on !